Auto refresh NavMenu with .Net 8 Blazor Server App
I created a .net 8 Blazor server app using Visual Studio template, everything works fine as expected. Next I added a timer to NavMenu so that it calls a function on a regular interval to get updated data from the database and shows the data on NavMenu.
Here is the code I added to NavMenu. This code works fine in previous versions of .net but no longer works in .net 8 as Dispose() function is called after OnInitializedAsync() killing the timer.
I would be appreciated if anyone can help, thanks.
UPDATE: Found the problem, adding this line to top of the file will fix it.
@rendermode InteractiveServer

@implements IDisposable

@* some other NavMenu code here *@

<h1>DATA: @this.data</h1>

@code
{
    private Timer? Timer = null;

    private int data = 0;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Timer?.Dispose();
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var tenSeconds = 10;

        this.Timer = new Timer(
          new TimerCallback(_ =>
          {
              InvokeAsync(async () =>
              {
                  await Task.Run(() => data++);/* simulate updating data from database */
                  this.StateHasChanged();
              });
          }),
          null,
          TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tenSeconds),
          TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tenSeconds));
    }
}


Works just fine. Because u say it's a menu, when the page is changed the Dispose is invoked if this is the case or u have other components that are causing the Dispose of the current one.

@DA It is correct that if the page is reloaded then NavMenu.dispose() is called, this is an expected behaviour. However in my case the page is not reloaded at all. Thanks for the comment.
